# Not sure if ZFS issue / ATA Linux controller issue?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, nas, zfs

I've been using ZFS for a few years now, but since moving to a new NAS I've been having a weird issue that I'm not even sure is ZFS-related.

I run a RAID-Z with 4 4TB disks, and every week or so (sometimes every 2/3 days) my `dmesg` output starts showing:

```
[181263.131531]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181264.346713]  sdc: sdc1 sdc9
[181265.722670]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181267.026973]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
[181269.223494]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181270.562879]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181271.955974]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
[181273.965705]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181275.147701]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181276.085743]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
[181276.880991]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181278.314671]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181309.204054]  sde: sde1 sde9
```

over and over again, and my pool starts resilvering, sometimes with checksum errors found, sometimes no errors found at all. I used the onboard SATA ports on my B450I Aorus Pro ITX motherboard, but recently got an ASMedia 109X cheap PCIe controller with 6 ports, and am getting the same result. Tried with kernel 5.4.x and 5.3.x, no difference.

The NAS is running OpenMediaVault 5.x, based on Debian 10. CPU is an AMG 200GE.

Any help welcome. Thanks!

UPDATE: these are the lines in the kernel logger immediately before:

```
[  541.834989] docker0: port 16(veth89a0c65) entered blocking state
[  541.834992] docker0: port 16(veth89a0c65) entered forwarding state
[19666.977275] perf: interrupt took too long (2505 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[65299.449905] docker0: port 17(veth342b51a) entered blocking state
[65299.449908] docker0: port 17(veth342b51a) entered disabled state
[65299.450102] device veth342b51a entered promiscuous mode
[65299.478322] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered blocking state
[65299.478326] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered disabled state
[65299.478433] device veth2afecda entered promiscuous mode
[65299.478566] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered blocking state
[65299.478568] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered forwarding state
[65299.840540] eth0: renamed from vethc2c1575
[65299.855726] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered disabled state
[65299.855786] docker0: port 17(veth342b51a) entered blocking state
[65299.855787] docker0: port 17(veth342b51a) entered forwarding state
[65300.287422] eth0: renamed from vethcda7502
[65300.303228] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered blocking state
[65300.303230] docker0: port 18(veth2afecda) entered forwarding state
[181263.131531]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181264.346713]  sdc: sdc1 sdc9
[181265.722670]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181267.026973]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
[181269.223494]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181270.562879]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181271.955974]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
[181273.965705]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181275.147701]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181276.085743]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
[181276.880991]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181278.314671]  sde: sde1 sde9
[181309.204054]  sde: sde1 sde9
```

and others related to `sdb`:

```
[    3.900995] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[    3.900997] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.901022] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.901024] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.901059] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.974764]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[    3.975748] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[181265.722670]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181270.562879]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[181275.147701]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
```

So it just seems that the drive enumeration lines come out of nowhere...?

Comment: I guess neighboring lines are relevant as well (there are other lines, right?). E.g. something like `[sdb] attached SCSI disk`.

Comment: updated the post with the rest of the log. I can post the full `dmesg` output somewhere if you think it'd be helpful.